# change column headers to be values in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

suppose that I have a dataset with this structure

```
pet_name    doggo     floofer    puppo     pupper 
A           None      floofer    None       None
B           doggo     None       None       None  
C           None      None       puppo      None 
D           None      None       None       pupper
E           doggo     floofer    None       None 
F           None      None       puppo      pupper
G           None      None       None       None
```

and I want to have a new column with the name dog_stage that contains the variables(doggo , floofer, puppo, pupper)

the final result will be like that

```
name    dog_stage
A       floofer
B       doggo
C       puppo
D       pupper
E       doggo, floofer
F       puppo, pupper
G       None
```

and drop the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both solutions filter only necessary columns:

```
df = df[['name','doggo' , 'floofer', 'puppo', 'pupper']].copy()
```

First solution join columns names if not contains `None` like Nonetype or like string `None` with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication by columns names:

```
#convert pet_name to index, if possible strings None replace and test not NaNs or not Nones
df1 = df.set_index('name').replace('None', np.nan).notna()

df1 = df1.dot(df1.columns + ',').str[:-1].reset_index(name='dog_stage')
print (df1)
      name      dog_stage
0        A        floofer
1        B          doggo
2        C          puppo
3        D         pupper
4        E  doggo,floofer
5        F   puppo,pupper
6        G
```

Another idea is join each row if not `None` in lambda function:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('name')
         .replace('None', np.nan)
         .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='dog_stage'))
```

Comment: but I have about 10 columns not just a one

Comment: @Moath - yes, it working for multiple columns, some problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: It gave me this error 
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: @Moath - In first or second solution?

Comment: and the first suggestion gave me that error 
TypeError: set_index() takes from 2 to 6 positional arguments but 9 were given

Comment: @Moath - it is weird, maybe data are different like in question. Is possible see what return first row of data like `print (df.iloc[0].to_dict())` of original data before this solution?

Comment: {'tweet_id': 892420643555336193, 'timestamp': Timestamp('2017-08-01 16:23:56+0000', tz='UTC'), 'source': 'Twitter for iPhone', 'text': "This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only ever appears in the hole of a donut. 13/10  'expanded_urls': 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1', 'rating_numerator': 13, 'rating_denominator': 10, 'name': 'Phineas', 'doggo': 'None', 'floofer': 'None', 'pupper': 'None', 'puppo': 'None'}

Comment: @Moath - thank you, solution was changed with `df = df[['name','doggo' , 'floofer', 'puppo', 'pupper']].copy()` bofore original answer.